# Changing the 'grey' colour after while a button is pressed - Cocoa Touch iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image

Hello
In IB I've used a rectangle button, once u press that button and hold, it goes a grey colour - I want to change that grey colour to an image i made.

So once the user touches the button, it goes to the image which I made

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the selected state image for the button to the image that you have created:

```
[self.btnMybutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: So would this be ok
'
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {
[self.btnMybutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play]; 
}
'

Comment: You need to set the selected state image in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. In your "oneSound" method if you put in UIButton * b = (UIButton *)sender; b.selected = TRUE; your gray button will remain visible when you click the button.

Comment: Sorry im new to this still. So i just add 
[self.btnMybutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

in my viewdidload?

Comment: Yes. If you want that your image shows the selected state i.e. the gray image after the button is clicked, you need to put UIButton * b = (UIButton *)sender; b.selected = TRUE; in your selector method. If you want the gray button image to only be visible when you click on the button image and as soon as you lift your finger up, you want the button image to go back to the original form, you need not put the selected = TRUE in your selector. You can try both ways and check the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder you can set an image for each state of the button. Simply click where it says "Default State Configuration" in the inspector and select "Highlighted State Configuration". Set the image you want in the "Image" or "Background" field and the button will use that image when it's touched.

Comment: Ive tried that but that never changes the image for me for some reason

Comment: @LAA if that did not work for you, then you did something wrong as that is an easy and correct way to achieve the desired effect. Maybe you forgot to save the changes within the IB or possibly a make clean helps.